# Accessing Public Page from AWS Ubuntu server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon Web service. I created an Ubuntu 16 instance with AWS. Installed Apache and restarted the service. But still I am unable to figure out how to access the start page from a browser. Which IP address should I use? Public ip or elastic ip? Also do I need to change any configuration file? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the public IP address, depending on your usecase you can even use an elastic IP address.

However you need to configure your security groups in order to access the web page.

- Go to your security groups
- Select the relevant security group
- Add inbound rule to port 80 (TCP)

Then you will be able to access the page. [Please refer this guide for more information.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html)

Comment: When accessing the webpage using my ipaddress it is showing the message "Your connection to this site is not private" and asking for credentials. How to remove that?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with me?

Comment: i updated the original question with screen shot. Thanks.

Comment: Here I see you are trying to access the web page, but trying ip address of your workstation. You should access it using the public IP address of the ec2 instance. Select your EC2 instance, In the description panel, there is public IPv4 address. `https://imgur.com/a/BQohm` refer the image. If your have any questions let me know.

Comment: ok i finally got it after changing the security group to accept all traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use public ip / public DNS. These both will change upon restart of an instance. Elastic IP is useful when you want your IP address to be persistent. e.g. To make an entry in your domain DNS records.

Make sure your default site is pointing to correct directory as you are going to access using IP address.

If your instance is in VPC then it must be in public subnet. (subnet with Internet Gateway route attached)